# How to convert JSON Array of Arrays to columns and rows

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql-9.3

I'm pulling data from an [API](http://data.rio/dataset/gps-de-onibus/resource/015b775c-f303-4e50-9089-4b97b0674030) in JSON with a format like the example data below. Where essentially every "row" is an array of values. The API doc defines the columns and their types in advance. So I know the col1 is, for example, a varchar, and that col2 is an int.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dat (data json);
INSERT INTO dat
VALUES ('{"COLUMNS":["col1","col2"],"DATA":[["a","1"],["b","2"]]}');
```

I want to transform this within PostgreSQL 9.3 such that I end up with:

```
col1 | col2
------------
  a  |  1
  b  |  2
```

Using [`json_array_elements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) I can get to:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(data->'DATA') 
FROM dat

json_array_elements
json
---------
["a","1"]
["b","2"]
```

but then I can't figure out how to do either convert the JSON array to a PostgreSQL array so I can perform something like `unnest(ARRAY['a','1'])`

Comment: What a horrid JSON document to work with.

Comment: I, sincerely, appreciate that validation.

Comment: It's like they heard about json once, but didn't understand it at all. Structured document? Nah, we'll just jam a representation of a relation into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### General case for unknown columns

To get a result like

```
col1 | col2
------------
  a  |  1
  b  |  2
```

will require a bunch of dynamic SQL, because you don't know the types of the columns in advance, nor the column names.

You can unpack the json with something like:

```
SELECT
  json_array_element_text(colnames, colno) AS colname,
  json_array_element_text(colvalues, colno) AS colvalue,
  rn,
  idx,
  colno
FROM (
  SELECT
    data -> 'COLUMNS' AS colnames,
    d AS colvalues,
    rn,
    row_number() OVER () AS idx
  FROM (
    SELECT data, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM dat
  ) numbered
  cross join json_array_elements(numbered.data -> 'DATA') d
) elements
cross join generate_series(0, json_array_length(colnames) - 1) colno;
```

producing a result set like:

```
 colname | colvalue | rn | idx | colno 
---------+----------+----+-----+-------
 col1    | a        |  1 |   1 |     0
 col2    | 1        |  1 |   1 |     1
 col1    | b        |  1 |   2 |     0
 col2    | 2        |  1 |   2 |     1
(4 rows)
```

You can then use this as input to the crosstab function from the tablefunc module with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('
SELECT
  to_char(rn,''00000000'')||''_''||to_char(idx,''00000000'') AS rowid,
  json_array_element_text(colnames, colno) AS colname,
  json_array_element_text(colvalues, colno) AS colvalue
FROM (
  SELECT
    data -> ''COLUMNS'' AS colnames,
    d AS colvalues,
    rn,
    row_number() OVER () AS idx
  FROM (
    SELECT data, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM dat
  ) numbered
  cross join json_array_elements(numbered.data -> ''DATA'') d
) elements
cross join generate_series(0, json_array_length(colnames) - 1) colno;
') results(rowid text, col1 text, col2 text);
```

producing:

```
        rowid        | col1 | col2 
---------------------+------+------
  00000001_ 00000001 | a    | 1
  00000001_ 00000002 | b    | 2
(2 rows)
```

The column names are not retained here.

If you were on 9.4 you could avoid the `row_number()` calls and use `WITH ORDINALITY`, making it much cleaner.

### Simplified with fixed, known columns

Since you apparently know the number of columns and their types in advance the query can be considerably simplified.

```
SELECT
  col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT
    rn,
    row_number() OVER () AS idx,
    elem ->> 0 AS col1,
    elem ->> 1 :: integer AS col2
  FROM (
    SELECT data, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM dat
  ) numbered
  cross join json_array_elements(numbered.data -> 'DATA') elem
  ORDER BY 1, 2
) x;
```

result:

```
 col1 | col2 
------+------
 a    |    1
 b    |    2
(2 rows)
```

### Using 9.4 `WITH ORDINALITY`

If you were using 9.4 you could keep it cleaner using `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT
  col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT
    elem ->> 0 AS col1,
    elem ->> 1 :: integer AS col2
  FROM
    dat
  CROSS JOIN
    json_array_elements(dat.data -> 'DATA') WITH ORDINALITY AS elements(elem, idx)
  ORDER BY idx
) x;
```

Comment: Column types are specified in advance in the API docs, editing my question now.

Comment: @raphael So you know the column types, and therefore the number of columns? That's kind of useful to know *before* solving it for the general case.

Comment: So all you need really is `json_array_element_text`? See above.

Comment: That function is not available in postgresql 9.3

Comment: @raphael Ah, right, yeah. It was a bit of an oversight with 9.3's json support.  You have to use the operator form `->>`. See [the manual for 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) and the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked fine for me, maybe it be useful for someone.

```
select to_json(array_agg(t))
 from (
  select text, pronunciation,
   (
     select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
    from (
      select part_of_speech, body
       from definitions
       where word_id=words.id
       order by position asc
     ) d
   ) as definitions
  from words
  where text = 'autumn'
) t
```

Credits:
https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql